# How to build a block of text and navigate within?

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to build a simple helper that would generate Markdown code blocks. This is ultimately going to be an `InputBox` where I will input the language.

When typing `mdcodego` I wanted to send

````
```go

```
````

with the cursor placed on the empty line.

I tried for now to just send the first line and it did not work

```
::mdcodego::Send Chr(0x60)Chr(0x60)Chr(0x60)text
```

gives the output

```
Send Chr(0x60)Chr(0x60)Chr(0x60)text
```

Same with `SendRaw`

What is the proper way to send such multiline strings?

Answer (score 1):

I moved to AHK v2 to future-proof my code and the code that works is

```
::mdcode::
{
Lang := InputBox(,  "input MD code language")
Send "{U+0060}{U+0060}{U+0060}" . Lang.Value . "`n`n`n{U+0060}{U+0060}{U+0060}{Up}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that single line hotstrings expect a literal string, which is what it output above (the same is usually true for the Send command). Try:

```
::mdcode::
InputBox, codeName, Code Name?, Input MD code language.
Send % Chr(96) . Chr(96) . Chr(96) . codeName . "{enter 2}" . Chr(96) . Chr(96) . Chr(96) . "{up}"
Return
```

The percent between the string forces an expression, when Send expects a literal string. Not sure about v2 ahk.